# Sending to closed UDP socket in C not throwing an error

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to "test" if a UDP socket is open as a way of terminating a program:

```
 int flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0);
        fcntl(s, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
        int x = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (x == -1)
        {
            char temp[] = "Testing Connection";
            int x = sendto(s, temp, sizeof(temp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, sizeof(si_other));
            printf("%d\n",x);
            if(x == -1){
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
```

However the if statement is not being triggered. The UDP socket that it is sending data to ran the following line(I know it ran because the print statement printed

```
    printf("Closing the socket\n");
    close(s);
    return;
```

The sendto continuously returns a positive value even though the udp socket it is trying to send to is closed. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: That's just how UDP works. It has no way of actually knowing if the data reached the other end. In order to successfully know, the other end has to acknowledge the packet.

Comment: And of course, there's no way for the other end to know if its acknowledgement was received. Thus you descend into the rabbit hole of protocols for reliable communication via an unreliable connectionless medium. It's all fun stuff if you like to tinker, but be aware there are plenty of libraries out there that will do the grunt-work for you.

Comment: from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto): _On success, these calls return the number of characters sent._ I'd be willing to bet your data is indeed getting sent, and you would see it in wireshark. Whether it's received or not is a different story, and it won't be if you're sending to a closed port. In fact as soon as `sendto` returns from transferring its data down into kernel it probably returns with success. I'd guess the data has a long journey from there before it actually makes it on the wire.

Comment: `send/to()` doesn't actually transmit anything, it just puts the data into the socket's outbound queue, and then returns the number of bytes queued. The socket stack will transmit the queued bytes on its own time. That being said, since you are `close()`'ing the socket's file descriptor, I'm betting that some other piece of code is opening a new descriptor that is using the same value as the old descriptor, so you end up writing your data to a completely different buffer than you are expecting. After you `close()` your socket, set its value to `-1` to avoid using someone else's descriptor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's what I thought also, but on re-reading I think he is calling `close()` on the receiving machine rather than the sending machine.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Upon re-reading it, I believe you are correct.

Comment: "UDP" means "**U**nreliable **D**atagram **P**rotocol".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since UDP is a datagram protocol and not connection oriented, there's no way to get connection-related errors with it directly.  You just send packets out into the internet and they may be received by someone or may be lost.

What you can do on some systems (such as Linux) is set the **IP_RECVERR** option on the socket.  If you do that, then you can use [recv(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) with the **MSG_ERRQUEUE** flag to see if any ICMP error messages related to packets you have sent have been received by the system.  The [ip(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) manual page has a description of this.  Note that *not* seeing an error response does not mean that the packet was received by someone waiting for it.  It might have been dropped for a variety of reasons before causing an icmp error, or the receiving machine might be configured to not generate errors (or might have gone away completely), or the icmp error itself might have been lost before getting back to you.

Most commonly however, you just send packets and wait for a response with some timeout(s) after which you resend things (and fail if you get no response after mulitple sends).  This is what TCP does "under the hood", waiting for ACK packets and resending data if they are not received (and eventually cutting the connection).